# Q: How to keep user from leaving custom map overlay in google maps on android

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, maps, coordinates

I'm trying to keep a user from leaving the custom overlay area that I'm putting up on my google map for an android device.

The problem is all my attempts to keep the user's view within GPS constraints end up fighting each other and bouncing the map back and forth.

What I did was I set up a listener and multiple methods to move the camera if it went out of bounds:

```
map.setOnCameraChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition position) {
        firstMapRegionCheck = true;

        VisibleRegion vr = mMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion();
        double left = vr.latLngBounds.southwest.longitude;
        double top = vr.latLngBounds.northeast.latitude;
        double right = vr.latLngBounds.northeast.longitude;
        double bottom = vr.latLngBounds.southwest.latitude;

        zoomFix(position);
        checkXAxis(position, left, top, right, bottom);
        checkYAxis(position, left, top, right, bottom);
        }
    });
}
```

I get all the latitude and longitude points first.  Then I run them through a method "zoomFix" that

```
public void zoomFix(CameraPosition position){
    if (position.zoom < DEFAULT_ZOOM) {
        CameraUpdate defaultZoomMove = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(DEFAULT_ZOOM);
        mMap.moveCamera(defaultZoomMove);
    }
    else if (position.zoom > 17){
        CameraUpdate zoomOut = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(DEFAULT_ZOOM);
        mMap.moveCamera(zoomOut);
    }
}
```

Originally I checked both the Latitude and Longitude both being too small and too big all at once.  I thought that was why they were fighting back and forth.

So I created two methods, one that checks the x coordinates and one that checks the y coordinates.

I thought by splitting the x and y coordinates up- that may have fixed the problem.  But it didn't.

checkXAxis:

```
public void checkXAxis(CameraPosition position, double left, double top, double right, double bottom){
    if (left < -87.896567) {
        LatLng southwest = new LatLng(bottom, -87.896567);
        LatLng northeast = new LatLng(top, right);
        LatLngBounds newBounds = new LatLngBounds(southwest, northeast);
        CameraUpdate camerageUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(newBounds, 0);
        mMap.moveCamera(camerageUpdate);
        zoomFix(position);
    }
    else if (right > -87.874628)
    {
        LatLng southwest = new LatLng(bottom, left);
        LatLng northeast = new LatLng(top, -87.874628);
        LatLngBounds newBounds = new LatLngBounds(southwest, northeast);
        CameraUpdate camerageUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(newBounds, 0);
        mMap.moveCamera(camerageUpdate);
        zoomFix(position);
    }
}
```

checkYAxis:

```
    public void checkYAxis(CameraPosition position, double left, double top, double right, double bottom){
    if (top > 43.178949){
        LatLng southwest = new LatLng(bottom, left);
        LatLng northeast = new LatLng(43.179501, right);
        LatLngBounds newBounds = new LatLngBounds(southwest, northeast);
        CameraUpdate camerageUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(newBounds, 0);
        mMap.moveCamera(camerageUpdate);
        zoomFix(position);
        if (firstMapRegionCheck){
            firstMapRegionCheck = false;
            checkXAxis(position, left, top, right, bottom);
        }
    }
    else if (bottom < 43.169292){
        LatLng southwest = new LatLng(43.169292, left);
        LatLng northeast = new LatLng(top, right);
        LatLngBounds newBounds = new LatLngBounds(southwest, northeast);
        CameraUpdate camerageUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(newBounds, 0);
        mMap.moveCamera(camerageUpdate);
        zoomFix(position);
        if (firstMapRegionCheck){
            firstMapRegionCheck = false;
            checkXAxis(position, left, top, right, bottom);
        }
    }
```

Anyways, if anyone can figure out how to prevent the fixes from fighting each other and not fully fixing the issue before hitting the onCameraChange listener again (which I assume is the problem) I would appreciate it!

Thanks!

Comment: I'm starting to think there is a need to keep track of previous map locations when it first enters the "onCameraChange" listener to prevent the jumping back and forth.

Comment: It appears it is starting to call the listener recursively before it has a chance to actually change the camera

Comment: I need to figure out a way to keep track of whether it's a programatic movement or a user movement- and ignore programmatic movements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setup up the listener:

```
mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition position) {
            VisibleRegion vr = mMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion();
            double left = vr.latLngBounds.southwest.longitude;
            double top = vr.latLngBounds.northeast.latitude;
            double right = vr.latLngBounds.northeast.longitude;
            double bottom = vr.latLngBounds.southwest.latitude;

            zoomFix(position);
            checkXYAxis(left, top, right, bottom);
        }
    });
```

Zoom check method:

```
public void zoomFix(CameraPosition position) {
    if (position.zoom < DEFAULT_ZOOM) {
        CameraUpdate defaultZoomMove = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(DEFAULT_ZOOM);
        mMap.moveCamera(defaultZoomMove);
    } else if (position.zoom > 17) {
        CameraUpdate zoomOut = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(DEFAULT_ZOOM);
        mMap.moveCamera(zoomOut);
    }
}
```

X and Y coordinate bounds:

```
public void checkXYAxis(double left, double top, double right, double bottom) {
    //X
    if (left < -87.896567) {
        left = -87.896567;
    }
    else if (right > -87.874628) {
        right = -87.874628;
    }
    //Y
    if (top > 43.178949) {
        top = 43.169292;
    }
    else if (bottom < 43.169292) {
        bottom = 43.169292;
    }

    //update camera position
    LatLng southwest = new LatLng(bottom, left);
    LatLng northeast = new LatLng(top, right);
    LatLngBounds newBounds = new LatLngBounds(southwest, northeast);
    CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(newBounds, 0);
    mMap.moveCamera(update);
}
```